# Why is Scala's syntax for tuples so unusual?

Tags: scala, tuples, iterable-unpacking

> *In mathematics and computer science, a tuple is an ordered list of elements. In set theory, an (ordered) n-tuple is a sequence (or ordered list) of n elements, where n is a positive integer.*

So, for example, in Python the 2nd item of a tuple would be accessed via `t[1]`.

In Scala, access is only possible via strange names `t._2`.

So the question is, why can't I access data in tuples as Sequence or List if it is by definition? Is there some sort of idea or just yet not inspected?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Scala knows the arity of the tuples and is thus able to provide accessors like `_1`, `_2`, etc., and produce a compile-time error if you select `_3` on a pair, for instance. Moreover, the type of those fields is exactly what the type used as parameter for `Tuple` (e.g. `_3` on a `Tuple3[Int, Double, Float]` will return a `Float`).

If you want to access the nth element, you can write `tuple.productElement(n)`, but the return type of this can only be `Any`, so you lose the type information.

Comment: I recall reading that now that case class inheritance is illegal, it's possible to strengthen the type of `productIterator` so that it could use a more specific type in some cases. This might be coming for 2.10, but someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It would be possible for the compiler to allow an expression like `t[1]` and keep all type information, and simply let `t[exp]` (where the result of exp is unknown at compile time) have a return type of `Any`, right? So it would seem the syntax different is more to drive home the point to the programmer that a Tuple is not a List.

Comment: @benzado You `t[exp]` is exactly what t.productElement(exp)` does. Note that square brackets are used in Scala for type parameters only.

Comment: @Kipton Barros: It is already working that way with `-Xexperimental` in 2.10 trunk, but only for case classes, not for tuples. No idea why.

Comment: Then why not support apply() method? List, Array and all other types support it. Seems weird that Tuple* does not support apply method(Which would have made it so much easier to write tupl(0), tupl(3) etc... ). IMHO, that would have made it more uniform with other types in the language.

Comment: Thing is, no one really uses `productElement` since you lose the type information…

Answer (score 40):

I believe the following excerpt from "Programming in Scala: A Comprehensive Step-by-Step Guide" (Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon and Bill Venners) directly addresses both of your questions:

> **Accessing the elements of a tuple**
>
> You may be wondering why you can't access the elements of a tuple like
>   the elements of a list, for example, with "pair(0)". The reason is
>   that a list's apply method always returns the same type, but each
>   element of a tuple may be a different type: _1 can have one result
>   type, _2 another, and so on. These _N numbers are one-based, instead
>   of zero-based, because starting with 1 is a tradition set by other
>   languages with statically typed tuples, such as Haskell and ML.

Scala tuples get very little preferential treatment as far as the language syntax is concerned, apart from expressions `'(' a1, ..., an ')'` being treated by the compiler as an alias for scala.Tuplen(*a1, ..., an*) class instantiation. Otherwise tuples do behave as any other Scala objects, in fact they are written in Scala as [case classes that range from Tuple2 to Tuple22](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/Tuple2.scala#L1). Tuple2 and Tuple3 are also known under the aliases of Pair and Triple respectively:

```
 val a = Pair   (1,"two")      // same as Tuple2 (1,"two") or (1,"two") 
 val b = Triple (1,"two",3.0)  // same as Tuple3 (1,"two",3.0) or (1,"two",3.0)
```

Comment: Pair and Triple are now deprecated. They were deprecated in Scala 2.11

Comment: Meanwhile, `Tuple1` has been added.

Answer (score 20):

One big difference between `List`, `Seq` or any collection and tuple is that in tuple each element has it's own type where in List all elements have the same type.

And as consequence, in Scala you will find classes like `Tuple2[T1, T2]` or `Tuple3[T1, T2, T3]`, so for each element you also have type parameter. Collections accept only 1 type parameter: `List[T]`. Syntax like `("Test", 123, new Date)` is just syntactic sugar for `Tuple3[String, Int, Date]`. And `_1`, `_2`, etc. are just fields on tuple that return correspondent element.

Comment: this is a much better answer than the others here. the key point is that Lists enforce homogenous types, while Tuples do not, which makes type checking more difficult.

Answer (score 12):

You can easily achive that with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

val t = ("a", 2, true, 0.0)

val s = t(0) // String at compile time
val i = t(1) // Int at compile time
// etc
```

A lot of methods available for standard collection are also available for tuples this way (`head`, `tail`, `init`, `last`, `++` and `:::` for concatenation, `+:` and `:+` for adding elements, `take`, `drop`, `reverse`, `zip`, `unzip`, `length`, `toList`, `toArray`, `to[Collection]`, ...)

Comment: A possible drawback is that compilation times can be longer, as this involves "type-level" programming, that is calculations expressed via the type system and implicits and done by scalac.

An additional feature that is both an advantage and a drawback is that calling these methods when you can't won't compile (e.g. calling t.take(5) in the example above), but you will typically get a weird error message by scalac instead of a clear explanation. A little work in shapeless may make this last point a little better though

Answer (score 8):

I think it's for type checking. As delnan says, if you have a tuple `t` and an index `e` (an arbitrary expression), `t(e)` would give the compiler no information about which element is being accessed (or even if it's a valid element for a tuple of that size). When you access elements by field name (`_2` is a valid identifier, it's not special syntax), the compiler knows which field you're accessing and what type it has. Languages like Python don't really have types, so this is not necessary for them.

Answer (score 7):

With normal index access, any expression can be used, and it would take some serious effort to check at compiletime if the result of the index expression it is guaranteed to be in range. Make it an attribute, and a compile-time error for `(1, 2)._3` follows "for free". Things like allowing only integer constants inside item access on tuples would be a very special case (ugly and unneeded, some would say ridiculous) and again some work to implement in the compiler.

Python, for instance, can get away with that because it wouldn't (couldn't) check (at compiletime, that is) if the index is in range anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the benefits Jean-Philippe Pellet already mentioned this notation is also very common in mathematics (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).  A lot of lecturers append indexes to tuple variables if they want to referring to the elements of a tuple.  And the common (LaTeX) notation for writing "with index *n*" (referring to the *n*-th element of the tuple) is `_n`.  So I find it actually very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Scala 3 [tuples](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/02/26/tuples-bring-generic-programming-to-scala-3.html) can be indexed in type-safe manner using [apply](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/44f1dc2f819bc33ba8bcd5782bcdba59f8a66702/library/src/scala/Tuple.scala#L260) method which is implemented with facilities such as match types, literal-based singleton types, and dependent functions types

```
/** Get the i-th element of this tuple.
 *  Equivalent to productElement but with a precise return type.
 */
inline def apply[This >: this.type <: NonEmptyTuple](n: Int): Elem[This, n.type] =
  runtime.Tuples.apply(this, n).asInstanceOf[Elem[This, n.type]]
```

giving

```
val t = (42, 3.14, "woohoo")
// t: Tuple3[Int, Double, String] = (42,3.14,woohoo)
t(0)
// res0: Int = 42
t(1)
// res1: Double = 3.14
t(2)
// res2: String = woohoo
```

Note the precise type which changes according to type of element at particular index. Also out of bounds index `t(3)` results in compile-time error

```
t(3)
  ^
  index out of bounds: 3
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the index `Int` must be a compile-time value. This won't work: `t("1".toInt)`