# What is the structure that is only enclosed by parentheses in scala?

Tags: scala

Here's the problem:

I intend to retrieve a (Int, Int) object from a function, but I don't know how to get the second element. I've tried the following commands so as to retrieve the second value, or convert it to a Seq or List, but with no luck.

```
scala> val s = (1,2)
s: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> s(1)
<console>:9: error: (Int, Int) does not take parameters
              s(1)
               ^

scala> val ss = List(s)
ss: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2))

scala> ss(0)
res10: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
```

Could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884298/why-is-scalas-syntax-for-tuples-so-unusual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val s = (1, 2)
```

is syntatic sugar and creates a [`Tuple2`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2), or in other words is equivalent to `new Tuple2(1, 2)`. You can access elements in tuples with

```
s._1 // => 1
s._2 // => 2
```

Likewise, `(1, 2, 3)` would create a `Tuple3`, which also has a method `_3` to access the third element.

Comment: Thanks bro, this is what I need. Actually, if you didn't give me this hint, not even do I know what keyword to google about... :]

Comment: It might be useful to add that another way to extract the content of the tuple is with pattern matching, for instance: `val (a, b) = (1, 2)` will affect a=1, b=2.