# Accessing Elements in List[Int] List[Int]

Tags: scala

```
List(1,2,3,4,5) partition (_ % 2 == 0)
```

produces

```
res40: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(2, 4),List(1, 3, 5))
```

How do I access the lists individually. res40(0) does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partition` creates a pair/tuple, and you can use `._1`, `._2`, etc to access elements in scala tuples, [see related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884298/why-is-scalas-syntax-for-tuples-so-unusual):

```
res0._1
# res2: List[Int] = List(2, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to assign each partition to a different val

```
val (even, odd) = List(1,2,3,4,5) partition (_ % 2 == 0)
```