# Scala: using map to extract secondary tuple values from a list

Tags: scala, tuples, mapping

My problem is the following:

I have a list of a specific type, lets call it `A`. 
`A` is defined by `A(name:String, value: Int)`.

This would make my list look like `[("a", 10) ("b", 12) ("c" 14)]`.

Now I want to use a map function to extract only the secondary values. that is construct a new list of the values `[10,12,14]`. I've been trying for over an hour but can't seem to get it working.

I've tried it with pattern matching in a map function and by trying to take the second element, i.e:

```
myList.map(_.value)
```

or

```
myList.map(_.2)
```

but can't seem to get it working.

Comment: If indeed these are tuples (and not instances of a case class like `A`) -
 use `myList.map(_._2) `

Comment: @TzachZohar is correct if your data structure is `Tuple`, but you are confusing engineers here showing a data class `A(name:String, value: Int)` .

Comment: You say the question is solved but neither answer has been accepted or even up-voted. That's not the way to say thanks on SO.

Comment: Yes, agreeing with @jwvh. If non of both answers solved your problem, give a self answer (or do you need more reputation to do so?). But if one answer solved your problem, accept it as answer, and vote every answer up, which you find good. It costs you less than editing the question, and the system will not recognize your edit as 'solved'. But it will recognize 'accepted answer' (colorized answer counter in the question list). Btw.: We avoid here greetings, 'Thanks in advance', 'Please help me out' and such. And the 'solved' message pollutes the auto generated excerpt - another point against.

Answer (score 3):

If your list is a `Tuple2` as

```
val list = List(("a", 10), ("b", 12), ("c", 14))
//list: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,10), (b,12), (c,14))
```

You have to use method `_1` to access the first element, `_2` to access the second, and so on. So doing the following should solve

```
list.map(_._2)
//res0: List[Int] = List(10, 12, 14)
```

But if its defined as a `case class` as

```
case class A(name:String, value: Int)
//defined class A

val list = List(A("a", 10), A("b", 12), A("c", 14))
//list: List[A] = List(A(a,10), A(b,12), A(c,14))
```

Then your way is correct

```
list.map(_.value)
//res0: List[Int] = List(10, 12, 14)
```

Answer (score 3):

if your data-structure is `case class` then, what you are doing is correct,

```
scala> case class Data(name:String, value: Int) 
// defined case class Data
scala> Seq(Data("a", 1), Data("b", 2), Data("c", 3)).map(_.value) 
val res6: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

But if its not a data class but a tuple, then you would have to get the second element using `tuple._2` or with pattern match as below

```
scala> Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)).collect {case (name, value) => value } 
res7: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Also Read [syntax for scala tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884358/432903)